# how do I pass the output of a bash command as parameters to another?

Tags: bash

I have a program that returns me a list of file names. I need to pass these file's contents to another program.

I know how to use `cat` to pass content:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | some_program
```

what I want to do is something like:

```
list=`get_file_list`
cat ${list} | some_program
```

Though doing the above will simply pass the content of the list variable, rather than the files' content.

Comment: No, `cat ${list}` concatenates the contents of the files named in `$list`.  If that's not what you want, I don't understand your question.

Comment: `echo "$list" | some_program` will pass the contents of the variable to the standard input of the program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To pass the output of,a program to another you can use xargs, for example

```
     find . -name "myfile*" -print | xargs grep "myword" $1
```

This one searches for files called myfile* and look for a key inside of them.

Comment: If that's a correct answer then `some_program \`get_file_list\`` is a simpler way to accomplish that in this particular case.

Comment: yeah! thx. Pls correct me if wrong; general format is something like:  .... | xargs $1 command $1 ...